# ArcGIS API calls with Android

Tags: java, android, arcgis

Are there API's available for arcGIS library implementation with Android, or do they use the same java APIs, as Android code is mostly Java

Answer (score 0):

This is the link the ArcGIS API's for android.

[Android API for ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/)